# the keyAttr of data-dojo-props doesn't work

Tags: dojo

here is my html file :

...

```
<span data-dojo-id="staffStore" data-dojo-type="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" data-dojo-props='data:../../staff.json'></span>
<input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox"
data-dojo-props="store: staffStore,
keyAttr: 'id',
searchAttr: 'staff_name',
autoComplete: true,
id: 'staff_name',
name:'staff_name',
value: '' "/>
```

...

and the json data goes as follows:

```
{
    identifier: "id";,
    label: "id",
    items: [{id: 982483700, staff_name: "guanyu";},{id: 582057769, staff_name: "zhangfei";},{id: 166802994, staff_name: "zhaoyun";}]
}
```

here is my problem:
when i use post method i have got  'staff_name' in the searchAttr: 'staff_name' passed to the background-appication ,but i want to have the 'id' in the keyAttr: 'id' passed to  background-application.in a word,i have passed made a wrong post action.can someone help me get out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` not `dijit/form/ComboBox`.

You can enter any text into a `ComboBox` therefore it cannot return `id` which is the reason it returns text (or label or `searchAttr`). `FilteringSelect` allows only to chose one of options and therefore it can return `id`, which it does.

See it in action and experiment at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/QzQ38/